# Is there a way to allow the placment of torches on Red Power 2 columns?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I have started messing the saw in the Minecraft mod Redpower 2. One of the items you can create is columns made from pretty much anything in the game.

The problem is I cannot seem to place torches on the columns. Has any seen a way to do this? it would make the columns so much more useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, because the microblocks created by the saw don't take up an entire block, you can't place torches on them. The one exception to this is if the block is the edge of a normal block as follows:

[image: torch demo]

Note, you can place one on the normal outside face of this block, but you couldn't place one on the inside, ie. over the dirt block, nor could you place a torch over either of the other stone blocks adjacent to the dirt block.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks for the explanation with a picture.